# The right method to display sub-categories for f.select in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, select

I'm building an Rails app were the user must select type of business via `f.select`.

I've used `f.select`before without any problems. but now I have to add sub-categories to the select.

In my app the user have to select one category and then have to select a sub-category according to the parent category.

How would I do it? is it possible?

This is basically what I need:

> **---category 1----**
>
> --sub-cat-1a--
>
> --sub-cat-1b--
>
> --sub-cat-1c--
>
> **----Category 2 ----**
>
> --sub-cat-2a--
>
> --sub-cat-2b--
>
> --sub-cat-2c--
>
> **----Category 3 ----**
>
> --sub-cat-3a--
>
> --sub-cat-3b--
>
> --sub-cat-3c--

I'm not sure how I would manage to do this, any suggestion would be great.

I've been googling around without success

I haven't start building this yet, I wanted to check here first if someone had a solution to this

Comment: if my answer helped, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: It helped, thanks, it has been marked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can definitely be done. You can use the standard rails form or the [`simple_form`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem to do this.

For example if you had categories and items to display, your standard rails form would look like this:

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>

    <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:category_id, Category.order(:name), 
                          :items, :name, :id, :title, 
                          include_blank: "Please Choose...") %>
<% end %>
```

This displays the main categories, and then the subcategories (items in this case) in each category. Its output looks like this, in which `accessories, canon camera` etc are the main categories, and `manfrotto tripod, canon 5D3` are the sub categories.:

[image: Category1]

It is similar to the html `optgroup` tag which looks like this:

```
<select>
 <optgroup label="Group 1">
   <option>Option 1.1</option>
 </optgroup> 
 <optgroup label="Group 2">
   <option>Option 2.1</option>
   <option>Option 2.2</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Group 3" disabled>
   <option>Option 3.1</option>
   <option>Option 3.2</option>
   <option>Option 3.3</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

Which produces:

[image: Category2]

Obviously you would have to modify this to fit your project, but it can definitely be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

For more flexible adjustment you can use select2 https://select2.github.io